# I want to make several containers move freely on the stack like windows on the desktop

Tags: flutter, stack, gesturedetector, pan

To do this, all the elements in the Stack have GestureDetector, and onPanUpdate made the elements move together in the direction the cursor moves.
In the process of onPanDown->onPanEnd->onPanDown->onPanUpdate, the elements are placed on top as desired and move well.
But if I go straight through the process of onPanDown->onPanUpdate, other elements will move.

If I do not change the order of the lists in the stack (when I go from onPanDown to onPanUpdate), it works fine.
but if I do so, onPanUpdate does not apply to the widget you want. How do we solve this?

-Error video
https://youtube.com/shorts/91O5IRPRbrs?feature=share

I changed GestureDetector behaviors and I changed the order of logic in various ways. But it doesn't work.

Comment: most likely your stack children should have the keys, for example `ValueKey(element.someId)`

Comment: The elements in the list have their own unique ID.
We've looked at it through various experiments, and the problem is as follows.
If there is a widget from [1, 2, 3] and 2 is raised to the top through onPanDown to reach [1, 3, 2], then onPanUpdate is applied to index 1, the original location of 2.
How can ValueKey address these challenges?

Comment: Thank you so much,,, It works with ValueKey. But I don't really understand why it works. What is the difference between having a ValueKey and not having one?

Comment: see first 3-4 minutes of https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3Dkn0EOS-ZiIc&ved=2ahUKEwiI-eSHo5z9AhUhtYsKHbubC30QtwJ6BAgyEAI&usg=AOvVaw3TAszOgjSQEEhMWPG9tHo4